# About JFR, how can I get the detailed info of the objects in memory view?

Tags: java, jvm, jfr

This is a screenshot of JProfiler. You see, I can only know `byte[]` has the most biggest size (235MB). However, it's not detailed. I don't know where the array is and the related variable name in my program.

[image]

I've tried adding some JVM args. But none of them effected.

Below is the JVM args.

```
  '-XX:+FlightRecorder' \
  '-XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=180s,settings=/opt/amazon/brazil-config/app/my_jfr_config.jfc,filename=myrecording.jfr' \
```

my_jfr_config.jfc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration version="2.0" label="Continuous" description="Low overhead configuration safe for continuous use in production environments, typically less than 1 % overhead." provider="Oracle">
    <event name="jdk.ObjectCount">
      <setting name="enabled" control="memory-profiling-enabled-all">true</setting>
      <setting name="enabled" control="heap-statistics-enabled">true</setting>
      <setting name="period">everyChunk</setting>
    </event>
</configuration>
```

And the JDK version is `openjdk 11.0.20 2023-07-18 LTS`.

Comment: It’s an educated guess, but it looks like you’re looking at statistics only. You’d have to make a heap dump, to be able to look at actual data. I’m not even able to tell the language of the labels in the screenshot, not to speak of their meaning. And I’m afraid I’m not the only one.

Comment: @Holger Sorry it's in Chinese, maybe because of my laptop's language. But I think you are right. I need to dump the heap.